# How to do remote debugging using intellij?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have created a maven plugin via maven-archetype-mojo. My intellij version is: IntelliJ 2018.1.7

And I have tried the following steps to initiate the remote debugging process.

1. I created a remote debug configuration and pointed it to port 8000
2. I run mvnDebug clean install in the terminal of the project folder, and it showed:

   1. Preparing to execute Maven in debug mode
      Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
3. Then I run the remote debug option, it returned:

   1. Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8000', transport: 'socket'
4. And in the terminal the plugin started to rebuild. After the rebuild remote debug session is disconnected.

This is my configuration for remote debug:
[image]

Any ideas?

Console output when connect with remote debug:

```html
Preparing to execute Maven in debug mode
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< com.alibaba.rhino:mc-generator >-------------------
[INFO] Building mc-generator maven plugin 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ----------------------------[ maven-plugin ]----------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ mc-generator ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/shuohuang/Projects/mcgenerator/target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.394 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-16T16:43:07+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Your remote debug setup looks correct, I tried it with a custom maven-plugin and it worked for me.

I would suggest you to update to the latest IntelliJ version, if possible.
This is currently *IntelliJ 2018.3*

If this does not resolve your problems, you should check your maven-plugin on errors. An error or wrong start of the maven-plugin could cause the build to break.

When possible, provide the output of the maven-plugin or code examples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added console output in the question. It seems remote debug session was disconnected after the plugin started to build.

Comment: This looks like maven only executes the `clean` goal.